# How do I create a static method for a JQuery plugin

Tags: c#, jquery

I'm working on a JQuery plugin. I want to define a statically visible method so I can access certain parts more easily. For instance, in C#, I would just do this:

```
public class MyPlugin()
{
  public static string DoSomething(object parameter) 
  {
    return DoImplementation();
  }
}
```

However, I can't figure out how to do this same type of thing in a JQuery plugin. Currently, I have the following:

```
(function ($) {
    $.myPlugin = function (element, options) {
        var defaults = {
            average: 0
        }

        myPlugin.init = function () {
            myPlugin.settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
        }

        myPlugin.doSomething = function (parameter) {
           // Implementation goes here
        }
    }
})(jQuery);
```

How do I create a statically visible method from a JQuery plugin?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$.myPlugin = { };
$.myPlugin.staticMethod = function(...) { ... };
```

Obviously, this cannot go inside of the actual `myPlugin` function, since that function is per-"instance" (actually, per-call).

The actual `myPlugin` method needs to be defined on `$.fn` (which is the prototype).

Comment: Would really appreciate a simple example here

Comment: @Anand: An example of what, exactly?

Answer (score 4):

You should be defining your plugin on $.fn instead of $. See http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring.
Then define a method on $.fn.myPlugin.doSomething.